# Apache Airflow: Multiple Trigger

Tags: triggers, conditional-statements, airflow

[In Airflow]
Please how I can trigger a task based on the result of another task? If task A result is true run Task 4 , if false ? re-run task A

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for the `BranchPythonOperator`, you can read about it [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching) -- here's some code copied from the documentation that branches based on the return value of a task named `start_task`:

```py
def branch_func(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom_value = int(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='start_task'))
    if xcom_value >= 5:
        return 'continue_task'
    else:
        return 'stop_task'

start_op = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    bash_command="echo 5",
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

branch_op = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=branch_func,
    dag=dag)

continue_op = DummyOperator(task_id='continue_task', dag=dag)
stop_op = DummyOperator(task_id='stop_task', dag=dag)

start_op >> branch_op >> [continue_op, stop_op]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this feedback , I'll try it.